# How to tell the while loop what data not to repeat?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been printing data in a simple way, really hard to believe that an HTML structure complicates me in the use of a `loop while` :(

I need to be able to add the information in two different containers, the container `<nav></nav>` and the container `<div id="ocultado" style="display: none"></div>` these containers should not be repeated, the only thing that It can be repeated is the content that is inside the containers.

Video URLs must go inside the container `<nav></nav>`

And the text contents, must go inside the container `<div id="ocultado" style="display: none"></div>`

In order to have this result:

```
<nav id="enlaces" class="vids">
    <a class="link" href="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4">test1</a>
    <a class="link" href="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4">test5</a>
    <a class="link" href="http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4">test6</a>
    <a class="link" href="#" id="link_1" >test10</a>
</nav>

<div id="ocultado" style="display: none">
    <div class="cuadro" id="c_link_1" >
        <h1>Print data</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cuadro" id="c_link_2" >
        <h1>Print data</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cuadro" id="c_link_3" >
        <h1>Print data</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cuadro" id="c_link_4" >
        <h1>Print data</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could create two `if` of checks according to the type of file format:

```
if($type_format === "video"){ }
```

And

```
if($type_format === "text"){ }
```

But again the complication comes from the containers that should not be repeated in the `loop while`

Finishing in this bad way:

```
<?php
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT type_format, url FROM multimedia");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($type_format,$url);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo '<nav id="enlaces" class="vids">';
            echo $url;
            echo '</nav>';

            echo '<div id="ocultado" style="display: none">';
            echo $url;
            echo '</div>';
        }

    }
?>
```

Could you explain how to prevent the containers from repeating please?

Comment: You could create an array with `['links' => [...], 'videos' => [...]]` in your current while-loop and then output them after in their correct places.

Comment: @Lou I also want to know the same, I will be attentive to your question, luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by grouping them under the correct type in an array:

```
$data = [
    'text'  => [],
    'video' => [],
];

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $data[$type_format][] = $url;
}
```

Then to output them in their respective containers:

```
// Output videos
echo '<nav id="enlaces" class="vids">';
foreach ($data['video'] as $url) {
    echo $url;
}
echo '</nav>';

// Output links
echo '<div id="ocultado" style="display: none">';
foreach ($data['text'] as $url) {
    echo $url;
}
echo '</div>';
```

#### Add more info

If you want to add more info for each url, you can simply do this in your loop:

```
$data[$type_format][] = [
    'url'   => $url,
    'title' => $title_video,
];
```

And then when you want to output the data:

```
echo '<nav id="enlaces" class="vids">';
foreach ($data['video'] as $info) {
    echo '<a class="link" href="' . $info['url'] . '">' . $info['title'] . '</a>';
}
echo '</nav>';
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, at this moment I will check, a doubt this goes as is, `$data = [
    'text'  => [],
    'video' => [],
];` with the empty brackets right?

Comment: @Lou - What do you mean? Just doing `'text' => []` will create an empty array as value for `text` (which we then push to inside the while-loop). So that's perfectly valid PHP syntax.

Comment: Perfect my friend, you are great ... thank you very much :)

Comment: Friend, please help me, in case I want to add the title of the video, what should I do? example: `echo '<a class="link" href="'.$url.'">'.$title_video.'</a>';`

Comment: @Lou - I've updated the answer with an example with more info for each URL.